# Servlet cxf of type class "myclass" does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, maven, deployment, cxf, wildfly

I can't deploy my project on Wildfly 10.
The problem is this :

```
Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SoapSd.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SoapSd.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet cxf of type class it.unibo.services.UniboServices does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.<init>(ServletInfo.java:98)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:725)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:281)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        ... 3 more
```

If I removed web.xml from my project and deploy it, It's work but the the wsdl is "not found".

Here my web.xml (is on src/main/webapp/WEB-INF ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SoapSd</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>it.unibo.services.UniboServices</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <persistence-context-ref>
        <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/LogicalName</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>unibodb</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>
</web-app>
```

And here my pom (and my project):
[pom](https://github.com/Diantha/SdWsProject/blob/master/pom.xml)

What's the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you intend to use `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` in place of `it.unibo.services.UniboServices` in your web.xml?

Comment: onestly I don't know what It means, I only want to use it as soap project

Comment: Try to change it to `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` and see if it works.

Comment: It not works, now the error is : Failed to link org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet (Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader @270421f5

Comment: (finder: local module finder @52d455b8 (roots: C:\Users\Liz\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\Liz\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))): org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener

Comment: You probably dont have CXF servlet library in your war or server. Try to include `cxf-rt-transports-http` in your pom (without provider scope).

Comment: cxf-rt-transports-http and cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty are different, right?

Comment: same error with cxf-rt-transports-http dependecies